# Finding the original Latin text of Seneca ("No tree becomes rooted and sturdy unless many a wind assails it.")

Tags: classical-latin, passage-identification, seneca-iunior

In what text of Seneca will I find the Latin for the statement, one English translation of which is, "No tree becomes rooted and sturdy unless many a wind assails it."

Answer (score 7):

It is to be found in [**Seneca the Younger, De Providentia (On Providence), book 1, chapter 4, section 16**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0012%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D4%3Asection%3D16)

> Non est arbor solida nec fortis nisi in quam frequens ventus incursat